# How to finish process with spatie/async?

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq

I'm trying to use the spatie/async lib for my RabbitMQ listener (based on a Symfony command). Here is the code that I use:

```
$this->pool = Pool::create()->sleepTime(5000)->concurrency(1000);    
$this->pool->add(function () use ($serializedAction) {
                    echo "We're in add of pool\n";
                    $this->client->send($serializedAction);
                    return true;
                })
                    ->then(function ($output) {
                        echo "Message sent to swoole\n";
                    })->catch(function ($exception) {
                        dump($exception);
                    });
```

My problem is that when I reach the concurrency parameters the command does not work anymore, and I never see the "Message sent to swoole" present in the function.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the problem was that I didn't use the wait() method of pool.

```
$this->pool = Pool::create()->sleepTime(5000)->concurrency(1000);    
$this->pool->add(function () use ($serializedAction) {
                    echo "We're in add of pool\n";
                    $this->client->send($serializedAction);
                    return true;
                })
                    ->then(function ($output) {
                        echo "Message sent to swoole\n";
                    })->catch(function ($exception) {
                        dump($exception);
                    });
$this->pool->wait();
```

Now it works.